# Appending many lists into a bigger list, and changing their sequence to fit the bigger list sequence

Tags: python, list, oop

I am doing a big O.O.P using python, I have a problem that I can not append more than two lists into one list.

This simple question might solve the problem:

I have three lists `first` ,`second` and `third`
I want to append the three lists in `bigger` list and make `second` list 3 times, and the `bigger` list will have one new sequence of elemments.

```
bigger = []
first = [1,2,3,4]
for l in first:
    bigger.append(l)
second = [1,2,3,4,5]
for m in second:
    for i in range(3):
        bigger.append(m+i)
third = [1,2,3]
for n in third:
    bigger.append(n)
print(bigger)
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
```

The desired output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
```

I hope that you can follow me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store the last element in `bigger` so far and add it to the elements in `second` and `third` as you append them. Also, the order of the loops are wrong when appending elements in `second`; the inner loop should be over `second`.

Also you mentioned you want to append to `bigger` element by element but lists have `extend` method that can extend `bigger` by another list.

```py
bigger = []
first = [1,2,3,4]
for l in first:
    bigger.append(l)
second = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(3):
    # track the last element
    last = bigger[-1]
    for m in second:
        # add the last here
        bigger.append(m+last)
third = [1,2,3]
# track the last
last = bigger[-1]
for n in third:
    # add the last here
    bigger.append(n+last)
print(bigger)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you really want. To get the desired output, it is enough to do:

```
list(range(1, 23))
```

Otherwise, to build the `bigger` list with the procedure that you described, this should work:

```
bigger = [*first, *(second * 3), *third]
```

The `second * 3` replicates three times the `second` list. The `*` in front of each list unpacks the values and puts them together into the `bigger` list.

Comment: I wish to append them element by element to follow my original program

Comment: @ElsaidYounes elements in desired output doesn't matches with elements in `first`, `second` and `third` lists. You either want to modify elements (then write how exactly) or not modify (then fix desired output elements with correct ones).